# Flask Jinja2 not rendering bootstrap carousel

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm wanting to render bootstrap carousel and other nested html elements. im newer to Jinja2 and didn't see anything on the internet talking about this particular issue.

here is my python

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    r = requests.get(os.environ['AWS_Product_URL'])
    prods = list(json.loads(r.text))
    return render_template("index.html", my_products=prods)
```

**this** works

```
{% for key in my_products %}
    <p><strong>{{ key["name"] }}</strong><span>{{ key["price"] }}</span></p>
{% endfor %}
```

but **this** doesn't

```
{% for key in my_products %}
     <div class="carousel-item">
         <p><strong>{{ key["name"] }}</strong><span>{{ key["price"] }}</span></p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I took an existing template and trying to make this dynamic. the class exists. I'm confused why Jinja2 is having trouble with a nested item in html.

Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably just missing to add class active to the carousel item

bootstrap carousel items requires at least one active element, all the others will be hidden.

so try out adding something like

```
{% for key in my_products %}
     <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}">
         <p><strong>{{ key["name"] }}</strong><span>{{ key["price"] }}</span></p>
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Just in case, here's template that I've tested with and it should be working fine assuming my_products is not empty.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
              {% for key in my_products %}
              <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %}active{% endif %}">
                <p><strong>{{ key["name"] }}</strong><span>{{ key["price"] }}</span></p>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev bg-dark" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next bg-dark" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```